# Css element hover starts whit animation but ends unexpectedly

Tags: css, animation, dom

When i hover the element the animation starts  but when i unfocus it the animation don't reverse back and everything gets back how it looked like before the animation started.
I want to make it to start with animation and end with animation.

```css
div#time{
background-color:#ecf0f1;
display:inline-block;
font-size:calc(3vh + 3vw);
border:5px solid #ecf0f1;
border-radius:0.7em;
top:2vh;
position:fixed;
width:30vw;
opacity:0.8;
 left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div#time:hover{
transition:1s;
border-radius:0;
background-color:#141414;
border:5px solid #141414;
color:white;

}
```

```html
<center><div id='time'>hiiiiiii</div></center>
```

https://codepen.io/abooo/pen/LeZOWR?editors=1100

Comment: The :not(:hover) pseudo-class also works.

Answer (score 4):

You have the transition property in the wrong place.

```css
div#time {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: calc(3vh + 3vw);
  border: 5px solid #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: 0.7em;
  top: 2vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 30vw;
  opacity: 0.8;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: 1s;
}

div#time:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #141414;
  border: 5px solid #141414;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div id='time'>hiiiiiii</div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move the `transition: 1s;` to the main selector, not the :hover one

```css
    div#time{
      background-color:#ecf0f1;
      display:inline-block;
      font-size:calc(3vh + 3vw);
      border:5px solid #ecf0f1;
      border-radius:0.7em;
      top:2vh;
      position:fixed;
      width:30vw;
      opacity:0.8;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: 0 auto;
  transition:1s;
    }
    div#time:hover{
      border-radius:0;
      background-color:#141414;
      border:5px solid #141414;
      color:white;
    }
```

```html
<center><div id='time'>hiiiiiii</div></center>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you move the transition to the actual div it works for both.

```css
div#time{
background-color:#ecf0f1;
display:inline-block;
font-size:calc(3vh + 3vw);
border:5px solid #ecf0f1;
border-radius:0.7em;
top:2vh;
position:fixed;
width:30vw;
opacity:0.8;
 left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition:1s;
}
div#time:hover{

border-radius:0;
background-color:#141414;
border:5px solid #141414;
color:white;

}
```

```html
<center><div id='time'>hiiiiiii</div></center>
```